# Laravel mail cannot attach a image?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I am trying to send a email using Spark Post

This is an error I am getting:

```
Swift_IoException 
Unable to open file for reading [C:\xampp\htdocs\liveandnow\public/images/logo.jpeg]
```

This is my welcomeEmail.blade.php

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path() . '/images/logo.jpeg') }}" ) }}">
```

This is WelcomeEmail.php

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('support@dev.dsd.com')
                ->view('emails.welcomeEmail');
}
```

and Controller:

```
Mail::to($request->user())->send(new WelcomeEmail());
```

Comment: Some time this error due to incorrect permission of the image file

Comment: Seems clear - your app can't open the file. It's not there, or it doesn't have permission to access it, or the `/` should be \ on Windows perhaps.

Comment: I tried \ doesn't work I tried it on ubuntu with 777 on the folder and still the same error